# Resetting game trouble in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm making a brick breaking game. I coded that when I pressed back button in-game, the game turns back to the main menu. And when I touch the Start button, I want to re-create the game. But my ball isn't moving after timer_StartCompletely is passed. In other words, my timer_ball isn't working. I have this code in my onBackPressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(status == INGAME) {
        scene.detachChildren();
        moveBall = false;
        status = MENU;
        ballX = (kamera.getWidth()/2)-(32/2);
        ballY = (kamera.getHeight()/2)-(32/2);
        ballSpeed = 3.5f;
        cx = (kamera.getWidth()/2)-(cubukTex.getWidth()/2);
        cy = kamera.getHeight()-25;
        this.mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(timer_ball);
        this.mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(timer_club);
        timer_ball.reset();
        musicBackground.play();
    }
}
```

My timer declaration:

```
    timer_StartCompletely = new TimerHandler(0.5f, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
            mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(timer_ball);
        }
    });
```

In my timer_ball, I coded movement of ball (the ball must move certainly, if timer_ball is called).

I have also a touch event that I control the touching buttons and registering timer_StartCompletely.

Comment: Well this might not solve anything but you don't really need the  mEngine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler); because the TimerHandler unregisters itself after the time passed.

Comment: @ChristophGerstner It doesn't unregister itself - an `UpdateHandler` cannot unregister itself because it doesn't hold a reference to the object which registered it. *But* it will not execute the callback again, unless you ask it.

Comment: Random, but I have a full brick breaker game working for AndEngine: https://github.com/pheonixblade9/Breakout

Comment: @Jong yes you are right! I mixed it up with the EntityModifier and its setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true).. sorry about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating your `TimerHandler`, you can pass a parameter called `pAutoReset` (You didn't pass it, so false is passed:

```
public TimerHandler(final float pTimerSeconds, final ITimerCallback pTimerCallback) {
   this(pTimerSeconds, false /*pAutoReset*/, pTimerCallback);
}
```

This parameter decides whether the `TimerHandler` should automatically reset itself after the time has passed (Which means that if you pass true, the callbacks are repeated).

**The problem here:** You didn't pass `true`, neither called the `reset` method of the `TimerHandler`. So if we look at the relevant code in `TimeHandler.java`:

```
if(!this.mTimerCallbackTriggered) {
    this.mTimerSecondsElapsed += pSecondsElapsed;
    if(this.mTimerSecondsElapsed >= this.mTimerSeconds) {
        this.mTimerCallbackTriggered = true;
        this.mTimerCallback.onTimePassed(this);
    }
}
```

Your callback executes once, and now `mTimerCallbackTriggered` is `true`, so it won't execute anymore.

**Solution**: Either call the `reset` method each time before registering the `TimerHandler`, or create it with `pAutoReset = true`.

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem, I added a second parameter with value **true** to my timer_StartCompletely. And the ball is moving after every restart. Thanks again...